# How to adjust tooltip distance in nv.d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was created a pie chart using nv.d3.js. In that I have created a tooltip for each field.

```
<nvd3-pie-chart
    data="exampleData"
    id="exampleId"
    showLabels="true"
    labelType="value"
    x="xPieFunction()"
    y="yPieFunction()"
    donut="true"
    donutRatio=".5"
    tooltips="true"
    tooltipcontent="toolTipContentFunction()"
    color="pieColorFunction()"
    donutLabelsOutside="false">
    <svg height="200" style="margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -29px;"></svg>
</nvd3-pie-chart>
```

**Script :**

```
$scope.exampleData = [
        {
            key: "Medium",
            y: 5
        },
        {
            key: "High",
            y: 1
        },
        {
            key: "Low",
            y: 1
        }
    ];

    $scope.toolTipContentFunction = function(){
        return function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
            return '<p>' + key +"-"+ y.value + '</p>'

        }
    }

    $scope.xPieFunction = function(){
        return function(d) {
            return d.key;
        };
    }
    $scope.yPieFunction = function(){
        return function(d) {
            return d.y;
        };
    }
```

Issue is tooltip is not showing over the pie chart, it is showing with long distance from pie chart when mouseover. How to adjust the distance based on mouseover.

Comment: Read this https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/372

Comment: I tried that but that would change all tooltips positions.

Comment: Well, Make a fiddle with sample data, then we could work on it.And find something.

Comment: @saikiran.vsk, In fiddle it is showing correctly.  


  http://jsfiddle.net/NChH9/78/

Comment: Oh...What we've to do :(

Comment: When I add margin: -75px; for tag <p> in $scope.toolTipContentFunction it is showing correctly but it si showing a small box below that. I don't know what is that.